# $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/geometry.inc.php';

Tags: root, document

I am a behinner in PHP and I'm using this code to include my geometry.inc.php file to include in my index page which is in a different directory
But it's is displaying me an error that "No such file or directory found"
What should I do Now

Comment: Please add a more descriptive title

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your include folder present at root directory, So to include any file we don't need to give the physical path of the file instead do

```
include('includes/geometry.inc.php');
```